# how to get text from following code

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

HTML Code

```
<label for="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_RadPanelBar1_i0_chkColumns_4">Job Title</label>
```

i have a text in page the above html code is what is can see in firebug for that text. i need to get the text "Job Title" from that .

the code which i have written is

```
String JobTitle= driver.findElement(By.id("ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_RadPanelBar1_i0_chkColumns_4")).getAttribute("label");

Reporter.log(JobTitle+" is Displayed",true);
```

i tried gettext Method but it is not working ...  when i used the above code it is displaying

null is Displayed

in console

Comment: The ID of your element is 'ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_RadPanelBar1_i0_chkColumns_4' and you are trying to pull it with 'ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_RadPanelBar1_i0_chkColumns_5'.This is not possible.Use a unique one. In case, if is changing dynamically, build xpath from a static parent.

Comment: now the code has been corrected ..

Comment: can you please re-edit the code once again ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you need to check if the label is visible or not as Selenium doesn't supports reading text for invisible elements. Secondly, as per your code, you are trying to check if label is visible or not. There is a property "Displayed" for that.
`driver.findElement(By.xpath("xPath for label")).Displayed`
This call would return you true or false depending upon label is visible or not.

No, if you want to read text, in that case .Text attribute returs the text if label is visible. If not visible, you should try .getAttribute("innerHTML"). That should work for you.

Answer (score 1):

Please make sure your HTML code is as your original application code. The following will work if both are same.

```
 String value=driver.findElement(By.xpath('//label[@for='ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_RadPanelBar1_i0_chkColumns_4']')).getText();
```

Answer (score 0):

The `<label>` tag does not have an `id` attribute, so you'll need to use its `xpath` instead:

```
WebElement label = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//label[@for='ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_RadPanelBar1_i0_chkColumns_4']"));
```

Then, you can use either:

```
String Jobvalue = label.getText();
```

Or:

```
String Jobvalue = label.getAttribute("innerHTML");
```